# What is the difference between the verbs "verki" and "skribi"?

Tags: word-usage

For example, I say "I am writing in my journal." Would I use *verki* or *skribi*? Are both acceptable?

Other examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

- `Skribi`: To write.
- `Verki`: To compose.

These words may be translated literally in your example:

- `Mi skribas en mia taglibro.`: "I am writing in my journal."
- `Mi verkas en mia taglibro.`: "I am composing in my journal."

`Verki` generally refers to the act of painstaking composition and synthesis rather than the specific act of writing itself, as is referred to by `skribi`.

- `Mi devas praktiki skribadon.`: "I must practice (the act of) writing."
- `Mi devas praktiki verkadon.`: "I must practice (the act of) composition."

---

**TL;DR: In this particular context, both `verki` and `skribi` can be acceptable.**

Answer (score 5):

You can *"verki"* without being [Thomas Mann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Mann). *Verki* simply means to create a *verko*. You could translate that as a work, or piece (of literature). As such, if you write a novel - during [NaNoWriMo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Novel_Writing_Month), for your desk drawer or for publication - you *verkis*.

If you have written a poem, you *verkis*.

Every type of writing is *skribi*, but *verki* is the specific concept of creating a piece (of literature).

Here are a few examples:

- Mi verkis belan rakonton.
- "...mi tamen verkis ĝin en ĉina lingvo, mia gepatra lingvo. Mi skribis ĝin ĉefe..."
- "Sube mi verkis elsendaĵon pri la Klubo de Romo..."
- "...kantoj, kiujn mi tradukis aŭ verkis por diversaj Esperanto-artistoj..."
- "Mi skribas leteron."

Comment: Is it only applicable to literature? Could one "verkas muzika verko aŭ arta verko"?